# Search RealmConfiguration by name and use it

Tags: android, realm

I am using Realm with my android project. Currently I am defining the default realm configuration in my application class as follows-

```
 @Override
public void onCreate(){
super.onCreate();
myApplication=this;
RealmConfiguration realmConfiguration = new RealmConfiguration.Builder(this).deleteRealmIfMigrationNeeded().build();
Realm.setDefaultConfiguration(realmConfiguration);
Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(new UnhandledExceptionHandler());

}
```

In current scenario only 1 user uses a device. She logs in to the app using her credentials and uses default realm configuration.

However with new requirements, the same android device can be used by different users and hence I need different realm configurations for each user so that each user has their own realm file right?

If this is true then what is the best way to manage realm configurations. 
Currently the only way to assign default configuration to realm is by using a realConfiguration instance. But how can I check if a realConfiguration exists (by name?) and then initialize Realm using that configuration?

Thanks

Apurva

Comment: `Map<String, RealmConfiguration> map = new HashMap<>(); if(!map.containsKey(user)) { /* realm config does not exist */ }`

Comment: Thanks. I can store the configuration in a map and check. But what happens when user shuts down the app and then restarts it. How do I load all configurations again.

Comment: I think this is almost the same question with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38443688/realm-configuration-management ? `RealmConfiguration` is a virtual concept which is only used to create the Realm file. Instead of checking if `RealmConfiguration` exsits, I think what you want is checking the Realm file exist. You can do `File.exist(realmConfig.getPath())`.

Comment: **All** configurations? Don't you only need the *current user*'s configuration?